# Help needed to connect lumia 630 to internet via laptop wifi

Tags: internet-sharing

I am using a wireless net connection through 3g dongle with my laptop(Windows 7).I tried to connect my lumia 630 to my laptop for internet access but the hot spot was not visible in search on my windows  phone. Even with connectify app there is no help.Please help,as i want to utilze my unlimited data plan.

Comment: *How* are you sharing your laptop's Internet conenction?

Comment: why are you searching for hot spot in your phone?